# Cambiar href a un elemento a

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero cambiarle el href a un elemento **a** de una celda especifica, en una tabla creada dinamicamente por boostrap tables.
Estuve tratando pero no puedo, lo que estoy haciendo es esto:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        debugger;
        let celda = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[3].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    }
```

Ahi obtengo bien todos los elementos **a** de las celdas en una determinada columna de la tabla, pero ahora no se como cambiarle el valor del **href** por uno que yo obtengo de una respuesta. Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes setear o modificar cualquier atributo de un elemento mediante el método `element.setAttribute(attr, value)`;

```
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    let celda = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[3].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
    celda.setAttribute('href', miHref); 
}
```

Comment: Funciona pero me pasa esto. Agregue como me dijiste **celda.setAttribute('href', 'www.google.com');** pero me redirige a: **http://localhost:60464/www.google.com**

Comment: Debes usar una ruta absoluta: `https://nombredehost/ruta`. En tu caso: `element.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.google.com');`

Comment: si es una url que no es de tu dominio tienes que poner la con el protoclo. Así `https://www.google.com`

Comment: Gracias a todos por su ayuda!